# Drupal atrium возвращает Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: drupal

Устанавливаю drupal сборку atrium, сервер wampserver.
Ставлю в php.ini max execution 300 сек перезагружаю серв - не помогает и все равно выводит

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:wampwwwatriumincludesfile.inc on line 958
```

Как лечить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему вставкой в file.inc

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

. Странно, почему не срабатывала опция в php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше делать это здесь:
locale.inc

```
drupal_set_time_limit(XXX);
```